# Calculate expanded_price using Django ORM

Tags: django

The raw SQL will perform mathematical calculations using calculated field, for example:

The item_price column contains the per unit price for each item in an order. To expand the item price (item price multiplied by quantity ordered), could do the following:

```
MySQL [distributor]> select prod_id, 
    -> quantity,
    -> item_price,
    -> quantity*item_price as expanded_price
    -> from orderitems
    -> where order_num = 20008;
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
| prod_id | quantity | item_price | expanded_price |
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
| RGAN01  |        5 |       4.99 |          24.95 |
| BR03    |        5 |      11.99 |          59.95 |
| BNBG01  |       10 |       3.49 |          34.90 |
| BNBG02  |       10 |       3.49 |          34.90 |
| BNBG03  |       10 |       3.49 |          34.90 |
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.027 sec)
```

How could I accomplish this with Django ORM?

Comment: Please add your **models.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides [**`annotate()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) method to annotate the results.

```
from django.db.models import F

result = orderitems.objects.filter(order_num=20008).annotate(
    expanded_price=F('quantity') * F('item_price')
)
```